# Families of distributions with a certain symmetry property?

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider the probability distribution $\mathcal{N}_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose density is $$(2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}||\vec{x}||^2} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_i^2}$$

This multivariate normal distribution has symmetry group $O(n)$. But the family of these distributions has two additional symmetry properties:

(a) If $X$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}_n$, and $\pi$ is an orthogonal projection onto an $k$ dimensional subspace, then $\pi \circ X$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}_k$.

(b) If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with distribution $\mathcal{N}_k$ and $\mathcal{N}_j$, then $X \oplus Y$ (the random variable on $\mathbb{R}^{k+j}$) has probability distribution $\mathcal{N}_{k+j}$

My question: is $(\mathcal{N}_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ the *only* family of probability distributions (up to rescaling) which has properties (a) and (b)?

Comment: I also wonder whether property (a) alone suffices. If we only care a finite family of distributions, $(\mathcal{D}_i : i \leq n)$, then it's easy to ensure property (a) holds: just let $\mathcal{D}_n$ be a distribution which has symmetry group $O(n)$, and let $\mathcal{D}_k$ for $k < n$ be defined to be the projection of $D_n$. This will have symmetry group $O(k)$. The problem is that it's not clear any such finite family with property (a) can be extended to an infinite family with property (a).

Comment: $F_n$ is radial so $F_n(x)= f_n(\|x\|^2)$ and the direct sum property means
$F_n(x)= \prod_{j=1}^n f_1(x_j^2)$. In $f_n(\|x\|^2)= \prod_{j=1}^n f_1(x_j^2)$ setting $x_{j } = 0 (j\ge 2)$ means $f_1 = f_n$ so that $f_1(m t) = f_1(t)^m$ whence $f_1(t) = e^{c t}$